# The use of the preposition OF is becoming confusing

Tags: prepositions

I am reading the book "Word Study and English Grammar" by Frederick William Hamilton, which says:

> [*Of* is superfluous in such phrases as *smell of*, *taste of*, *feel of*](https://ideabooks.net/page,6,28664-hamilton-frederick-w-frederick-william-word-study-and-english-grammara-primer-of-information.html)”.

I want to know exactly what the writer meant as he did not include the best way to use *of*. Should we avoid the use of *of* in the use of the above words?

Comment: Perhaps you could include more information. For example, what is the title of the book? Does the author suggest alternatives to the use of _of_ in expressions such as _This cheese smells of soap_?

Comment: Thank you. Kindly check it now.

Comment: Thanks for including the title. But again, without more context it is difficult to know exactly what the author finds problematic and what correction/improvement is suggested. _feels of_ sounds odd, but _smells of_ and _tastes of_ are common idioms. For example: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smell+of

Comment: Using the examples “smell of, taste of, feel of,etc.” the author says that ‘of’ is used quite frequently.  ‘superfluously = in sufficient number/ quantity’. It is neither to use, nor to avoid, but to let one know how often it is used.

Comment: Please include the full paragraph and the previous paragraph to show the context.

Comment: @Kris that’s all it said

Comment: For the record, the publication seems to belong to 1918, republished and also digitized later.

Comment: The author is likely speaking of constructions like “This smells of peppermint” or “This tastes of lemon.” or “This has the feel of leather”  If he’s saying what I think he’s saying, then I think he’s wrong

Comment: I suspect his intent is that you should use an adjective rather than "of", e.g. "lemony smell" rather than "smell of lemon".

Comment: I have no idea what the author proposes as an alternative. The sentence *I like the smell flowers* means something quite different from *I like the smell **of** flowers.* You can't just drop the preposition.